# How can I get CLion to ignore my generated docs folder?

Tags: clion, indexer

I've opened a certain C++ + CUDA project in CLion. This project has a subdirectory of documents, generated by doxygen. Annoyingly, these get indexed for occurrences of identifiers and show up in searches (!)

How can I make CLion ignore these folders when indexing?

Note: I know I can make it not show this subdir in the project tree view if it's in my `.gitignore`; but its contents still gets indexed.

Using CLion 2020.2.3 on Devuan Linux Beowulf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easy. Mark folder with documentation as 'Excluded':
[image]